# Checking checkbox in listview from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

```
<ol class ="lists" id ="list1"data-bind="foreach: quiz.questions" >
    <li class="lists" >
        <div>
            <label class="question_que"><span data-bind="text: Name"></label></span>
            <ul  data-bind="foreach: Options">
                <li >
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" data-bind="checked:IsAnswer">
                        <label for="checkbox-1a" class="ch_box"><span data-bind="text:Name"> </span></label>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The KO binding is working, and I'm assigning true and false in `IsAnswer`, but the `list view` is sometimes not showing the checkbox.

How it can be done without losing style?

Comment: Sometimes not showing what? Entire questions are being omitted? Options?

Comment: The checkbox, since it is inside a `foreach`, should not have a static `id` attribute. `id` is supposed to be unique in the document.

Comment: thanks,it works ,but it loses the style.

Comment: Why should the style change after removing just the static id?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're styling your control using an ID selector like `#checkbox-1a`.

You must not use the same ID for different DOM elements in the same document. That's HTML specification. If you do so, you can get strange behaviors.

To avoid repeating the id you can do two different things:

1) remove the id, and wrap the checkbox inside the label tag, so that the id isn't needed:

```
<label class="ch_box">
  <input type="checkbox" .../>
  <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
</label>
```

2) bind the id attribute and use `$index` to generate unique ids, like this:

```
<label data-bind="
  attr{id: 'check-box-q' + $parentContext.$index() + 'a' + $index()}" ...
```

Probably, with any of this two solutions you'll have to change the CSS styles, but you're not showing them in your question

Comment: Since it's inside two `foreach` loops, `$index` won't be enough to be unique. You'd need `$parentContext.$index()` as well.